# Google Plugin for Eclipse cannot be properly Installed

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have installed
**Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6**
**Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0**
in my Eclipse-Helios-3.6 but cannot find the google plugin icon in my toolbar and also I'm able to find **Google** in Windows>>Preferences.

Operating system-Ubuntu

Comment: Have you checked that the plugin is actually listed as installed? Try `Window` -> `Install/Update` -> click the link `Uninstall or update`.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are able to see google in windows preferences i am assuming that the installation did work. Have you tried creating a new GWT Project. The GWT button might not show if the project is wrong.

Comment: Sorry sir,Now I'm not able to view even Google in windows preferences.My issue is getting complex day by day.

Comment: can't comment so I write it here. Bananeweizen is probably right. Just type eclipse download in google. take the newest version. And choose eclipse classic. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. This is basically just a java editor. After that try installing the plugin again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the pre-packaged Eclipse in Ubuntu (that version is often quite outdated). Get a current version from the Eclipse website instead and install it in a directory that you like (thereby avoiding problems with the Eclipse update mechanism, which doesn't fit the Linux directory guidelines very well).

Comment: Can it be possible for you to provide me relevant link.